# Anonymous function causing id to be blank

Tags: javascript, dom, anonymous-function

I wanted to use DOM elements instead of innerHTML so I changed this

```js
cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="button"  class="blue" onclick="edit(this.id)" value="Edit" id=edit-button' + (i + 1) + '></input>';
```

into this

```js
var newEl = document.createElement("input");
newEl.className ="blue";
newEl.value= "Edit";
newEl.id="edit-button " + (i + 1);
newEl.type="button";
cell3.appendChild(newEl);
newEl.onclick=function() {edit(newEl.id)};
```

how do I fix the argument of the function edit becoming null/empty?

Comment: newEl.addEventListener("click", function() { edit(newEl.id)});  ??

Comment: newEl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {edit(e.target.id)});

Comment: Im not entirely sure on this. But I believe this is because the variable newEl doesn't exist anymore when you click whatever you're clicking since it's in a completely different scope. When you work with events and want to do anything with the thing that fired the event always use the event that gets passed to the function to grab the element.